# How to make jaw go along with Endo head

Tags: modeling, rigging, pose-mode

I'm new to rigging. I'm trying to rig an [Endo head](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20endo%20head&source=lnms&tbm=isch) for my robot but the jaw doesn't go along with the head and when I try to parent the jaw to the head, the bone will get disconnected from the objects. I tried making a separate bone and a copy of the head bone but nothing works.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, why don't you join the jaw bones to the armature? If you don't want for some reason, you can parent the jaw to the head bone: Select the jaw armature, select the body armature, switch to Pose mode, select the head bone (called Bone.010) and press Ctrl P > Bone

Comment: @moonboots joining would deform it but parenting worked, thanks

Comment: You have unaplied scales everywhere, maybe you should check that too, but it would probably mean deparent first and so on...

Comment: What exactly is applying scale ? I'm still a beginner, this is one of my first models

Comment: Maybe you should check some tutorials about rigging, Darrin Lile and Sebastian Lague have made great ones, unfortunately it's for Blender 2.7